# Sort a list of Dictionaries by list of strings

Tags: python

How can i sort a list of dictionaries using a predetermined list of strings

Ordered List of Strings

```
["Apple", "Watermellon", "Orange", "Grape"]
```

Collected Dictionary Data

```
{
    "Grape": {"value": 3},
    "Watermellon": {"value": 5},
    "Orange": {"value": 8},
    "Apple": {"value": 1}
}
```

Desired order of dictionary...assuming I'll have to convert it to a list of some sort in order to maintain order.

```
{
    "Apple": {"value": 1},
    "Watermellon": {"value": 5},
    "Orange": {"value": 8},
    "Grape": {"value": 3},
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code that didn't produce the desired output?

Comment: A dictionary has no order, you'll either have to use an `OrderedDict`, change your data structure or rely on the fact that, in Python >= 3.7, *dictionary insertion order* is guaranteed (which I personally find shaky).

Comment: What about keys that don't appear in your list?

Comment: What’s the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to rely on the insertion order of dictionaries and python versions, you can turn it into a sorted list, for example:

```py
order = ["Apple", "Watermellon", "Orange", "Grape"]

data = {
    "Grape": {"value": 3},
    "Watermellon": {"value": 5},
    "Orange": {"value": 8},
    "Apple": {"value": 1}
}

ordered_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: order.index(item[0]))
print(ordered_data)

>>> [('Apple', {'value': 1}), ('Watermellon', {'value': 5}), ('Orange', {'value': 8}), ('Grape', {'value': 3})]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Python3.6` ([guaranteed](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) in `Python3.7`), `dict`s are ordered by insertion order.

So a simple comprehension dict do the trick:

```
print({key: d.get(key, {"value": 0}) for key in l})
```

I took the liberty to default value in case your key is not present.

For versions before `3.6` you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Source: [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> Performing list(d) on a dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in insertion order